# How can I get my slide show to loop back to the beginning using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I got my slide show page to work good enough for my JavaScript class, but I was unable to get it to restart at the beginning of the slide show when it reached the end. I can't see what I need to start back over at index [0] rather than stopping at [11].
Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the relevant portion of my JavaScript file. I left my comments in - hopefully it's not too messy from that. It runs okay until it gets to end, then just stops.

```js
const pics=document.querySelectorAll(".dogPic");
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((b,i)=>b.addEventListener("click",nextpic(2*i-1)));
pics.idx=0;
function nextpic(inc){return function(){
 pics.idx=(pics.idx+inc+pics.length)%pics.length;
 pics.forEach((p,i)=>p.style.display=i==pics.idx?"":"none");
}

setInterval(nextpic(1),5000);nextpic(0)();
}
```

```css
/* Fade fx for pics */
.dogPic {
    animation-name: fadePic;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
@keyframes fadePic {
    from {opacity: .1}
    to {opacity: 1}
}

/*button styling - gives animation when clicked*/
.directionButton{
        background-color: #CEF9F2; 
        border: none;
        color: black;
        padding: 15px 15px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 24px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
        position: absolute;     
}
.directionButton:active{
        box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
        transform: translateY(4px);
}

/*postioning for directional buttons*/
#moveForward{
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
#moveBack{
    margin-left: 2%
}
```

```html
    <h1 id="pageTitle">slideShow</h1>

    <button class="directionButton" id="moveBack">Previous</button>
    <button class="directionButton" id="moveForward">Next</button>

    <main class="grid" id="mainBody">
        <section class="photoArea">
            <div id="photoList">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/200.jpg" class="dogPic">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/300/200.jpg" class="dogPic">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/239/300/200.jpg" class="dogPic">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/240/300/200.jpg" class="dogPic">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/241/300/200.jpg" class="dogPic">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/242/300/200.jpg" class="dogPic">>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
```

Comment: Consider making a snippet of your code with the related HTML and any needed CSS. Your code as posted seems to malformed; perhaps you lost some of the end parts when pasting?

Comment: In case you didn't know what @Mark meant by "snippet", [here is some info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulo operator `%` to ensure you only get valid array indexes:

```js
const pics=document.querySelectorAll(".pic");
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((b,i)=>b.addEventListener("click",nextpic(2*i-1)))
pics.idx=0;
function nextpic(inc){return function(){
 pics.idx=(pics.idx+inc+pics.length)%pics.length;
 pics.forEach((p,i)=>p.style.display=i==pics.idx?"":"none");
}}

setInterval(nextpic(1),5000);nextpic(0)();
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/200.jpg" class="pic">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/300/200.jpg" class="pic">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/239/300/200.jpg" class="pic">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/240/300/200.jpg" class="pic">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/241/300/200.jpg" class="pic">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/242/300/200.jpg" class="pic">
<br><button>&lt;</button> <button>&gt;</button>
```

Ok, ok, so here is a version with a forward and a backward button ...

The expression

```
pics.idx=(pics.idx+inc+pics.length)%pics.length
```

makes sure that the calculated index will always be within the valid range (as long as the increment `inc` is not lower than `-pics.length`).

Comment: OK as a pure running display but perhaps update with the next/back click handlers as the OP has as it is likely the more challenging part of the ask.

Comment: Thanks to all for the rapid response!

Comment: I have tried Carsten Massman's fix. Unfortunately, now it's showing all the photos on the page. I assume I have screwed it up, but I will wrestle with it some more and update my additional screwups. Thanks to all for the rapid and thorough responses!